# mod rewrite is not working and not giving any error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We want to change links "www.example.com/page/login/" to "www.example.com/sayfa/giris". I tried this: `RewriteRule ^page/^(.+[^/])$/ /sayfa/^(.+[^/])$ [L]` But nothing is change. Is there any error?

Thank you very much for your response @geert3 and @anubhava. But all trying failed. Here is my .htaccess content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /(uploads/.*) $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You can not do that. You can do `www.example.com/page/login/ -> www.example.com/sayfa/login/` or `www.example.com/page/xxxxx/ -> www.example.com/sayfa/onerealpagename/`

Comment: So you want your users to visit `www.example.com/sayfa/giris` in the browser and internally load content from `www.example.com/page/login`?

Comment: @anubhava, Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule /(uploads/.*) $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sayfa/giris/?$ /page/login [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

- Make sure there is not .htaccess in `/sayfa/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to remove the second `^` and add an initial slash after the first `^`. The slash after `$` must be removed.

`^/page/(.+[^/])$`

`^` at the start of an expression means "beginning of line" (i.e. in your case you want `/page` in front of the path). After a square bracket it means "none of the listed characters" (i.e. in your case no slash). In other places, it makes no sense.
`$` means "end of line" so it makes no sense to add stuff after it.

Also as @Croises noted, you can't have "matches" on the right. Right side is your target URL, so there you can either re-use matches you made on the left side, use environment variables or hardcoded text, but no new matches. So no `^`, `[]`, `$` etc.

So for instance the whole rule would become:

`^/page/(.+[^/])$ /sayfa/giris [L]`

Comment: and yet you're using `$/`